# Feigenbaum attractor is uncountable set?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

How to prove that Feigenbaum attractor (appearing at the accumulation point in logistic map) is an uncountable set? (I am not a mathematician but know how to prove that a Cantor set is uncountable.)

Comment: Math necromancy: If I understand you correctly, the basic intuition is that any point in the Feigenbaum attractor can be understood as the result of an infinitely long sequence of binary choices (as to whether to go up or down at each bifurcation).  I.e., there is a bijection between the attractor and infinitely long binary strings.  Thus both are of cardinality $2^\mathbb{N}$.